# How to display button or anchor tag value with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to display a button or anchor tag value based on what my angular variable return as true or false. Here is a snippet of it.

```
<a href="#" id="verify">{{userInformation.value}}</a>
```

userInformation.value return true/false. Now what I want is to display particular value for the button element based on what the angular returns.

Something like :

```
<a href="#" id="verify">{{userInformation.value === true ? displaysomething : displaysomethingelse}}</a>
```

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: You can use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Comment: What is wrong with code shown? Can use a ternary in angular expressions

Comment: its not working, nothing gets returned

Comment: something else is wrong as I created a jsfiddle for the same and it's working.

Comment: nope I tried this, doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: provide a jsfiddle of your code @BishwaroopChakraborty

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<a href="#" id="verify">{{userInformation.value ? 'Hello': 'Hi'}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing ng-if, consider creating a function in the controller that would decide what to display for you. This would allow you to keep the business logic in your controller and out of your template and you could unit test (which is generally a good idea). Also, it would be open for more than just two conditions for value (e.g. if you had to check more than just true/false). Example here:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MainController', function() {

  // initial user info object
  this.userInformation = {
    value: true
  };


  // swap values for demo purpose
  this.swapValue = function(obj) {
    obj.value = !obj.value;
  };

  // logic for display lives here
  this.getUserInfoDisplay = function(userInfo) {
    if (userInfo.value) {
      return 'Display something';
    } else {
      return 'Display something else';
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Controller as syntax -->
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
  <a href="#">{{ctrl.getUserInfoDisplay(ctrl.userInformation)}}</a>
  <br />
  <button ng-click="ctrl.swapValue(ctrl.userInformation)">
    Swap Value
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to display these based just on what the variable returns and not on clicking it. I dont want to click on it to change the value to true/false.

Comment: The button was simply to show how changing the value is driven from the controller method. Obviously your data will be set elsewhere.